# Atualizar o tabela do HTML usando JQuery e PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Ainda sou novato nessa area de programação Web, estou me virando aqui,

Tenho um código que efetua o teste de ping de alguns hosts e retorna se estão online ou não.
Porem vi em um outro código que achei na Web que é possível atualizar uma linha individual na tabela e utiliza um spinner para mostrar que o a linha esta sendo atualizada.

```php
<?php
$title = "Monitora"; // website's title
$servers = array(

  'HOST 1' => array(
    'ip' => '10.65.1.1',
    'info' => 'HOST 1',
  ),
  'HOST 2' => array(
    'ip' => '10.65.2.2',
    'info' => 'HOST 2',
  ),
  'HOST 3' => array(
    'ip' => '10.65.3.3',
    'info' => 'HOST 3',
  ),
)
?>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/2.3.2/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    /* Custom Styles */
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Host</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($servers as $name => $server) :

          $ip =    $server['info'];
          exec("ping -n 2 $ip", $output, $status);


          if ($status == 0) {
            $status_ping = "success";
          } else {
            $status_ping = "error";
          }


        ?>
          <tr class="<?php echo $status_ping ?>">
            <td><i class="icon-spinner icon-spin icon-large"></i></td>
            <td class="name"><?php echo $name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $server['info']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $status_ping ?>
          </tr>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

[image: Exemplo do spinner rodando enquanto atualiza a linha que esta offilne]

Comment: E qual é a dúvida?

Comment: @FranklinBarreto eu não sei como fazer para atualizar a linha da tabela de forma individual...

Comment: Você está dando ping apenas uma vez, quando a página é carregada. não tem como atualizar apenas uma linha ai. você só vai verificar novamente atualizando a página novamente. você pode por exemplo separar a verificação php do front e fazer uma requisição ajax a cadas 5 segundos para todas as linhas da tabela que ainda estão pendentes

Comment: Tenta colocar um id nas linhas que você precisa atualizar, a lógica é a mesma.

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta não está tão clara, mas fiz algo semelhante, não está tão dinâmico, mas funciona!

```js
$(function() {
// dados armazenados como objeto (opcional, podes obter através de API)
    var hosts = {'Host1': '10.65.2.2',
        'Host2': '10.65.1.1', 
        'Host3': '127.0.0.1', 
        'Host4': '10.65.3.3'}; 

    Object.entries(hosts).forEach(([name, host]) => {
        checkHost(name, host);
    });
});

function checkHost(name, host) {
    fetch(`check.php?host=${host}`, {method:'get', mode:'cors'}).then(res => res.json())
        .then((j) => {
            $('tbody').append(`<tr id="${name}" class="${j.class}">
                <td><i class="icon-spinner icon-spin icon-large"></i></td>
                <td>${name}</td>
                <td>${j.host}</td>
                <td>${j.status} (${j.ping})</td>
                <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return checkHost('${name}', '${j.host}');">Verificar</a></td>
            `);
        });
}
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Monitora</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/2.3.2/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Monitora</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Host</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*check.php*

```
<?php  
    
    error_reporting(0);

    if (($_GET['host'])) {
        exec("ping -n 2 {$_GET['host']}", $output, $status);
            // obtem o valor da Média fornecido pelo comando ping usando regex
            preg_match_all("/= ([0-9ms]+)/", $output[9], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

            // imprime um objeto json para voltar como response no fetch.
            print_r(json_encode(array(
                'host' => $_GET['host'],
                'status' => $status == 0 ? 'Sucesso' : 'Erro',
                'class' => $status == 0 ? 'success' : 'error',
                'ping' => trim($matches[2][1]) == '' ? '0ms' : trim($matches[2][1])
            ))); 
    }
```

Ficou desta forma, como mostra a imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que o tenha ajudado! Bons estudos :)

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.

Olha, tive um problema parecido com o seu um tempo atrás, no caso eu tinha um div com ID = ping, e dentro dessa div eu tava usando o codigo abaixo:

> exec('ping -n 1 google.com',$available, $retorno);
> if ($retorno == 0) {
> echo '';
> echo '
>
> OK
>
> ';
> } else {
> echo 'Down';
> }

E precisava atualizar ela de modo que estivesse pingando ele criava uma div com id ok e com o background verde ou vermelho caso não estivesse pingando, ai para atualizar somente a div ping que é onde estava o codigo php eu usei esse codigo em javascript/jquery:

> Citação
> $(document).ready(function(){
> setInterval(function(){
> $("#ping").load(window.location.href + "#ping");
> }, 1000);
> });

Espero que seja util pra você.

Comment: No caso eu consigo atualizar a linha da tabela ou só conseguiria através de uma div?
Fiz com a div e deu certo, porem eu precisava atualizar as linhas da tabela de forma individual

Comment: Diogo, desculpa, acho que não soube me expressar bem na minha ultima resposta e droparam ela rsrs, mas então eu tentaria fazer dessa maneira:(document).ready(function(){ setInterval(function(){ $(".table").load(window.location.href + ".table"); }, 1000); });